# <xsl:variable> which is an xml file on intranet

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to process a config file (which is in xml format).

The processing requires inputs from another xml file which is hosted on the intranet.

When I copy the file to D:, I can use `<xsl:variable>` to read the xml file as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="vProds" select="document('file:///d:/packages.xml')" />
```

However, when I specify the intranet location http://abc.xyz/api/xyz.xml, as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="vProds" select="document('http://abc.xyz/api/xyz.xml')" />
```

I get an exception "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

What is the correct way to read a file from the intranet?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify which processor you are using?  It is possible that either your processor can't retrieve a url (in which case it may signal this error).  I suspect it is more likely that it is caused by the server mangling the document in some way.  Try to open the url in a browser and see if the document looks ok.

Comment: @Matthew the document looks fine in the browser. If I save it in an xml file on my local machine and give the path to the locally saved file, the xslt can process it.

Comment: Which processor are you using?  Are you sure that it can retrieve a url?  This is likely specific to your processor.

Comment: I am testing this through VS2015

Comment: Also, I realized that when I open the file in IE, I see xml but when I open the url in VS browser I see JSON data!

Comment: I can help with the syntax and how the software should behave, but I'm not familiar with that software to be able to give any advice for it specifically.  I suspect that you have just zeroed in on the problem though - if your processor is receiving JSON when it retrieves the document, it won't be able to parse it and will give that error, so it appears that the problem is with serving the document and not with your XSLT.  There may be a configuration setting for the software that is causing it to request JSON, or it may be the servers fault.